# I need to divide an integer by 12 and if the result is a float, add 1 to it, in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just cannot figure this out, nor find any kind of similar question that makes any sense to me. My problem: I am extracting records from a database and displaying them in multiples of 12 per panel on my web page. I therefore need to know how many panels to display all records, using JavaScript (or possibly JQuery). Example:

```
records = 27;
panels = records / 12; //(which is 2.25)
```

Obviously I will need 3 panels to display all 27 records, but how can I get that from the result of 2.25? I've tried also using % instead of / but somehow I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
records = 27; panels = Math.ceil(records / 12); // 3
```

Round up.

Answer (score 0):

if result is not fully divisible by 12, then use Math.ceil (2.25) which equals 3